# How to maintain an aspect ratio of a div inside another div

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, css3pie

So I have a div and which contains two `divs` one on top of the other. I want the one on top to have an aspect ratio of `4:5` with 100% width as it will contain an image of that ratio and then remaining height goes goes  to the second `div`.

This is as far I could go

You can find all the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-heisenberg-pr21k?file=/src/styles.scss)

note: I wish to maintain that aspect ratio as the user shrink the screen size, try to shrink the width on the sandbox example to see

```
&_product{
                    overflow: hidden;
                    padding-top: 800.34px / 591.44px * 100%;
                    background: rgb(207, 206, 206);
                    position: relative;
                    max-width: 232px;
                    // max-height: 317.313px;
                    &_inside {
                      display: grid;
                      // grid-template-columns: 1fr 
                      // grid-template-rows: 1fr 80px;;
                      position: absolute;
                      top: 0;
                      left: 0;
                      width: 100%;
                      height: 100%;
                    }

                    border: 1px solid rgb(131, 72, 72);
                    position:relative;
                    width:100%;
                    height:fit-content;
                    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
                    overflow:hidden;
                    &_imgbox{
                      height: 100% ;
                      border: 1px solid red;
                      box-sizing:border-box;
                      position: relative;
                      // img{
                      //   width:100%;
                      //   display:block;
                      //   margin:0;
                      // }
                      &_aspect {
                        position: absolute;
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 5px/4px*100%;   // My attempted calculation
                        background: blue;
                        top: 0;
                        // left: 0;


                      }
                  }
                }
```

html

```
    <div class="Recommendations_container_recomendation_box_product">
                            <div class="Recommendations_container_recomendation_box_product_inside">
                                <div class="Recommendations_container_recomendation_box_product_imgbox">
                                    <div class="Recommendations_container_recomendation_box_product_imgbox_aspect">

                                        {/* <img src="https://images.sportsdirect.com/images/products/62310640_l.jpg" /> */}
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="Recommendations_container_recomendation_box_details">
                                    <div class="Recommendations_container_recomendation_box_details_price">$55.99</div>
                                    <h2>Brand Name<br /><span>Mens Designer T-shirt</span></h2>


                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I am unable to make the top inside div have an aspect ratio of 4:5 of the width @RishabhdevTyagi do you please know how to

Comment: Did you try setting the width and height in px?

Comment: That is the issue I want the height to grow on that same ratio as the user shrinks the screen width, check the sandbox example above to get the effect @RishabhdevTyagi

Comment: when the outer container grows, do u want that inner ones also grow to the full size and match the outer container?

Comment: Yes please, on the width side. I need the height to be  5:4 of the container width @RishabhdevTyagi

Comment: I have given all my best to this point

Comment: Ok, I will try and update here.

Comment: aight, big thanks in advance @RishabhdevTyagi

Comment: One more Idea, remove height:fit-content; from .Recommendations_container_recomendation_box_product{} css and add width: 20vw;
    height: 25vh; to see the effect.Shink and expand the browser window for it.Also, remove max-width:232px; to see it growing.

Comment: I didn't want it to expand relative to the whole window, just its parent container @RishabhdevTyagi I left you a link on the answer you provided, take look at it.

Comment: also big thanks, really appreciate your effort of trying to help

Comment: Most Welcome!I'm happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.Recommendations_container_recomendation{

  display:flex;

}
```

Comment: I am don't think that is what I want, however I figure it out. Where I was doing the calculation on `height` it was supposed to be on `padding-top`. checkout the output [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-heisenberg-pr21k?file=/src/styles.scss:2634-2810)

Comment: set width in vw(viewport width) and height in vh(viewport height)

Comment: checkout, the output from the sandbox link, it is fixed

Answer (score 0):

I had this fixed by calculating the ratio on padding top instead of the height

[fixed here](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-heisenberg-pr21k?file=/src/styles.scss:2634-2810)

```
padding-top: height: 5px/4px * 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Flex can really help you here. I attached a simplified version of what you are trying to achieve.

It's just few lines of CSS. Hope it helps.

If you change the `heigh`t of the box you'll see it maintains the ratio. 
The ides is that inside the box, each item got a `flex` value. So the sum of all the value is then divided by the individual flex value to determine the ratio.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.four-fifth {
  flex: 4;
  background-color: red;
}

.remaining-height {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="four-fifth">
        Content
    </div>
    <div class="remaining-height">
        Additional content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the try, I am not sure if I formulated the question wrong but I wanted to keep the ratio when the width change not the height. I had it fixed though [fixed here](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-heisenberg-pr21k?file=/src/styles.scss:2634-2810)

Comment: Sure and It will also keep the ratio when you change the width